# Can I convert a Dashboard in react type Script to react js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I bought a Dashboard from Metronic to use it but I found it in TypeScript and I don't know it , How can I use it with ReactJs not TypeScript ..Does anyone face this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have type casting issues. I suggest you get pure JavaScript one! or try to learn TypeScript it's also fun to write.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but I want to use at ongoing project so I don't have time now to learn TypeScript because I have a deadline